# ArcGis' python library (arcpy) are imported so long

Tags: arcpy, import, performance, windows

`python -c import time; t1 = time.clock(); import arcpy; print('{0} seconds'.format(time.clock() - t1))
3.60283379862 seconds`

It takes this long each time i launch my script or test.

Is there any way to make import faster? Probably somehow cache arcpy module in memory between launches?

OS - Windows 7.

Comment: You could try this [building a simple server/client](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16430894) for imports

Comment: As many of the proposals require a running cmd-shell, why not using a simple cmdline inside the script? The modul cmd is a standard modul and easy to use.

Comment: Steven, thanks, i have my script working on production and test (my computer) environments. Even if i use client&server approach on test, i have to use usual 'import arcpy' on prod, so i have to maitain two different ways in my script to interact with arcpy. Also with client-server it is unclear for me how to return results of arcpy's functions calls and how to get errors.

Comment: Andreas, excuse me, but i'm not sure i understand, what you're trying to offer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to execute `import arcpy` in under 4 seconds, the DLL files are already cached in memory, and that's as fast as you can hope to achieve. It's a very large library, and it takes Python a while to read and register.  The best way to reduce repeat `import` cost is to not `exit()`.